# Set an horizontal scroll to my Barchart in swift

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts framework from Daniel Cohen Gindi which is great but:

I would like my barchart to scroll horizontally to see additional data.

I've tried to add a scroll view but it didn't worked. I also tried different value like

```
barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)
barChart.moveViewToX(90)
```

but it didn't work.

Is anyone managed it ?

Fingers crossed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the scroll will only happen if you zoomed in. By default, all data are plotted on the canvas, so nothing to scroll.

You can try increase `scaleX` by code, to see if your code works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430461/how-to-add-marker-to-center-position-in-ios-charts-while-scrolling-horizontally

Comment: Can you show me the code? It scaleX seems to be readonly property of ChartView now!

Comment: Please look into this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343054/how-to-manually-add-marker-in-swift-charts-at-fixed-point#62343054

Answer (score 9):

First set bar chart data and then call 'barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)'

Comment: please add some explaination for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, ordering matters for this to work. You need to call setVisibleXRangeMaximum after chartView.data = data and all kinds of attributes assigned for barChartView